# TS2322 Error when extending Button, component property not found. What is the correct way to type?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I am migrating from MUI v3 to v4. I have some wrapped Button components that extend some styling and other properties on the regular Material UI Button component. Since upgrading to v4, I get type errors with this. I am utilizing react-router-dom as my routing library.

When passing the forwarded ref components as written in the updated Button example in the MUI v4 documentation (here: https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#third-party-routing-library) I get a type error that `component` does not exist in the props type I've provided for my wrapped button.

I've tried various combinations of types from the Button component to see if something else might work but it seems that `ButtonProps` should cover it based on the `OverrideProps` type that `ButtonProps` is built from.

Here is my reproduction in code sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-button-type-issue-dihdd?from-embed

Note: It takes a minute for the type errors to show up while Code Sandbox chugs through the types.

[image]

Comment: Following https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15695 for this issue.

Comment: and https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15827

Comment: for search visibility you should probably copy the error message and TS error code `ts2322` to your question - otherwise searchers will not find this.

Answer (score 3):

This is happening for two reasons:

1. `ExtendedButton` *contains* a `MUIButton` (which has the `component` property), but `ExtendedButton` isn't a `MUIButton` itself (so it doesn't have the `component` property).
2. The `component` property is defined on `OverridableComponent`, not `OverrideProps`.

You need to implement the component property and pass it along to `MUIButton`:

```
const Button: React.FC<Props & { component: React.ElementType }> = ({
  component,
  // ...
}) => (
  <MUIButton
    component={component}
    // ...
  >
    // ...
  </MUIButton>
)
```

For reference, here is where `component` is defined in MUI:

```
export interface OverridableComponent<M extends OverridableTypeMap> {
  <C extends React.ElementType>(props: { component: C } & OverrideProps<M, C>): JSX.Element;
  (props: DefaultComponentProps<M>): JSX.Element;
}
```

Comment: P.S. thank you for the codesandbox.io link, it made this easy to diagnose!